# Given final block not properly padded

Tags: spring, spring-security

Buenas a todos, estoy teniendo problemas en una aplicacion web en Spring que usa certificados y un servicio CAS/SSO para autentificarse, el problema viene desde el principio.

Tengo las propiedades externalizadas, así que recibo todos los datos de archivos externos (esto lo he comprobado y efectivamente, estoy usando bien las propiedades externalizadas...

Cargo un certificado externalizado para el entorno en el que estoy trabajndo,el error parece ser la clave (password) siendo incorrecta, **PERO no es asi**, he abierto el certificado usando la misma clave, he desencriptado la clave encriptada y me da muestra exactamente la misma que estoy intentando.

**app-cxf-client.xml**

```
  <bean id="usernameTokenOutInt" class="es.*******.*****.security.osgi.interceptor.WSS*******OutInterceptor">
    <property name="id" value="es.******.*****.wss.UsernameToken"/>
    <property name="properties">
      <map>
        <entry key="action"                 value="UsernameToken"/>
        <entry key="passwordType"           value="PasswordText"/>
        <entry key="passwordCallbackClass"  value="es.****.*****.security.osgi.header.passwordHandler.UsernameCallbackHandler"/>
        <entry key="addUTElements"          value="Nonce"/>
        <entry key="actor"                  value="http://www.**********.org/********/Authentication/1.0"/>
      </map>
    </property>
  </bean>

<bean id="signatureOutInt" class="es.*****.******.security.osgi.interceptor.WSS******OutInterceptor">
    <property name="id" value="es.*****.****.wss.Signature"/>
    <property name="properties">
      <map>
        <entry key="action"                 value="Signature"/>
        <entry key="user"                   value="ALIAS_CERTIFICADO"/>
        <entry key="passwordType"           value="PasswordText"/>
        <entry key="passwordCallbackClass"  value="es.*****.*****.security.osgi.header.passwordHandler.UsernameCallbackHandler"/>
        <!--<entry key="signaturePropFile" value="client_sign.properties"/>-->
        <entry key="signaturePropFile"      value="config://webapp/client_sign.properties"/>
        <entry key="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference"/>
        <entry key="actor"                  value="http://www.******.org/*****/Authentication/1.0"/>
        <entry key="signatureParts"         value="{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}UsernameToken;{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body;{Element}{http://*****.****.es}****Headers"/>
      </map>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

**ERROR**

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: SECURITY_FAILED
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:156)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.recuperarURIPersona(Unknown Source)
    at es.****.****.consolas.webapp.services.BDOrgService.obtenerUriUsuario(BDOrgService.java:98)
    at es.****.****.consolas.webapp.services.BDOrgService.obtenerUsuario(BDOrgService.java:69)
    at es.****.****.consolas.webapp.services.LoginService.guardarAtributosSession(LoginService.java:72)
    at es.****.****.consolas.webapp.interceptors.UserSessionInterceptor.guardarAtributosSession(UserSessionInterceptor.java:105)
    at es.****.****.consolas.webapp.interceptors.UserSessionInterceptor.preHandle(UserSessionInterceptor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:958)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:236)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Error during Signature: 
    at org.apache.ws.security.action.SignatureAction.execute(SignatureAction.java:64)
    at org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:202)
    at es.****.****.security.osgi.interceptor.WSS****OutInterceptor.access$200(WSS****OutInterceptor.java:51)
    at es.****.****.security.osgi.interceptor.WSS****OutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS****OutInterceptor.java:277)
    at es.****.****.security.osgi.interceptor.WSS****OutInterceptor$WSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(WSS****OutInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:533)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Signature creation failed
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:539)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:459)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.build(WSSecSignature.java:365)
    at org.apache.ws.security.action.SignatureAction.execute(SignatureAction.java:61)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: General security error (The private key for the supplied alias does not exist in the keystore)
    at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin.getPrivateKey(Merlin.java:725)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:482)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:435)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1023)
    at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin.getPrivateKey(Merlin.java:711)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:991)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:847)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore.implDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:399)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore$PBEWithSHA1AndDESede.engineDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:431)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:371)
```

No se que mas codigo necesitan para identificar donde puede estar el error, pidan y les proporcionaré lo que pueda, Gracias de antemano

**EDIT**: Tengo otra apliación con exactamente la misma configuracion creada en la que me funciona correctamente todo

**EDIT 2 **: Comprobado que el error no es leyendo propiedades externalizadas al realizar unas modificaciones en el codigo para leer propiedades desde un archivo local. Estas propiedades, al igual que el certificado son iguales (cambiando valores que apuntan a URLs por rutas_de_archivos) y sigue produciendose el mismo error en las mismas lineas de codigo

PD: los asteriscos (***) es informacion sensible al proyecto que no es necesaria conocer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**

Mi problema estaba, como era de esperar, en mi código, concretamente en

```
<bean id="signatureOutInt" class="es.*****.******.security.osgi.interceptor.WSS******OutInterceptor">
    <property name="id" value="es.*****.****.wss.Signature"/>
    <property name="properties">
      <map>
        <entry key="action"                 value="Signature"/>
        <entry key="user"                   value="ALIAS_CERTIFICADO"/>
        <entry key="passwordType"           value="PasswordText"/>
        <entry key="passwordCallbackClass"  value="es.*****.*****.security.osgi.header.passwordHandler.UsernameCallbackHandler"/>
        <!--<entry key="signaturePropFile" value="client_sign.properties"/>-->
        <entry key="signaturePropFile"      value="config://webapp/client_sign.properties"/>
        <entry key="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference"/>
        <entry key="actor"                  value="http://www.******.org/*****/Authentication/1.0"/>
        <entry key="signatureParts"         value="{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}UsernameToken;{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body;{Element}{http://*****.****.es}****Headers"/>
      </map>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

en `<entry key="passwordCallbackClass value=es.*****.*****.security.osgi.header.passwordHandler.UsernameCallbackHandler"/>`

esa clase insertaba por debajo sin saberlo un password por defecto que sobreescribia al suministrado por mi sin darme cuenta, cree otra clase indicando que cogiera la contraseña de la propiedad externa.